# What is the detailed meaning of Shad Yantra in the Dashpaad board (10x10)?

Tags: history, chess-variants, chessboards

Shad Yantra (pronounced as Skhad Yantra or Shad Yantra) is the 6 Principles of War according to scholars. What are all these Shadgunya principles and how significant are they in this ancient dashpada game?

Comment: Why people who know 0 about Dashpada, Shadyantra and history are down voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shad Yantra is more or less mentioned by many Indian scholars in Ancient times, and their 6 principles are almost similar.

Dashpaad board (10×10) was designed in such a manner that Shad Yantra game can accomodate these 6 principles protocols.

Modern Chess has only Four principles with grossly incorrect moves.

One such verse in Samskrit language talks about Shad Yantra:

```
वश्याकर्षणयो रक्ता श्यामा स्तंभविरोधयोः।
निग्रहोच्चाटयोः कृष्णा श्वेता मोक्षपरोक्षयोः।।
```

Shad Yantra eloborates its basic principles in 6 categories:

```
    वश्य (Attracting)
    स्तंभ (Stopping)
    विरोध (Opposing)
    निग्रह (Killing/Ending)
    उच्चाटन (Warding off)
    मोक्ष / शान्ति (Peace)
```

Other writers have their own version.

References:
#1 आकाश भैरव कल्पम् (A poetic verse or Shlok from Aakash-Bhairav-Kalpam).

#2 कौटिल्य षाड्गुण्य सिद्धांत | षाडगुण्य नीति (Shadguna and RajMandalam Principles by Kautilya)

Comment: "*Modern Chess has only Four principles with grossly incorrect moves*."   What do you mean by "*grossly incorrect*"?

Comment: As per Modern Chess, knight moves in L shape only, jump over the opponent. All pieces move like rocket. Modern chess is incorrect as per the original game and purpose for why it was invented. Grossly vague move is the correct word..